# CD Rom Door Does Not Shut

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, compact-disc

My CD ROM door only remains closed when the computer is turned (Off) or if I am playing  CD music Disc.  I tried programming my computer because Windows Media Player refused to burn my CD's.  I did however manage to burn a music CD last night.  This morning the CD ROM door refused to remain closed.
How can I program my ACER ASPIRE 7736Z-4088 CD drive door to remain closed and not reopen when the computer is turned off or I'm playing a music CD?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "programming my computer"? Do you mean that you ran a firmware update on the drive itself? Are there notifications on screen when the drive opens itself?

Comment: So the drive pops open *as soon* as you turn the laptop on, or does it do this only after loading Windows 7?